# Convert shp to kml in ArcMap but it is not placed correctly in Googleearth

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, shapefile

I have a shp polygon in GGRS87/Greek Grid. I want to display the polygons on googleearth. I use "layer to kml" tool in ArcMap. However when I open the kml in googleearth the polygons are not aligned correctly (they are all moved southwest from their right position).

Has to do with the transformation of datums?

Notes: 
1) in the tool I clicked on environments and as coordinate system I chose GCS_WGS_1984 and for transformation: GGRS_1987_To_WGS_1984
2) before applying the layer to kml tool, I tried to use Project tool to change the coordinate system to WGS84. But for an unknown reason I didn't have the option to use geogr. tranformation

Comment: did you use ArcMap for the projection?

Comment: while not a direct answer this page may help you https://rmseifried.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/the-impossible-made-possible-projecting-greek-data-into-utm/

Comment: If you're not getting a geographic transformation, try redefining the data's coordinate system to the Esri GGRS87/Greek Grid version. There may be a difference in the GGRS87 definition that's making it not equal the one in the transformation.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: You might want to look in the Source tab under your layer properties, to see if the Reference System was assigned with the Esri-recognized WKID code.  If not, you might want to run the GP "Define Projection", as GGRS87, and then proceed to Project and then Conversion.

Comment: The data I use have the following coord. system: GGRS87 / Greek Grid
WKID: 2100 Authority: EPSG Projection: Transverse_Mercator (that's what you see in properties of the shp). It didn't work to use "Define Projection" as GGRS87

Answer (score -1):

Use WEB Mercator it would work.

Comment: Before converting the shp to kml, I first used the Project tool and as output coord. system I selected "WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere" (from Proj. C.S\World) and used the GGRS_1987_To_WGS_1984 transformation.  Unfortunately, the kml produced in the next step has the same false alignment (shifted southwest)

Comment: Can you share some sample data so that i can reproduce the problem and check it.

Comment: Data: https://we.tl/uX9caVwXUl   I am still trying but nothing yet. And here is a paradox: When I open the data with QGIS and save them as kml (I select WGS84, EPSG4326 as CRS)  the polygons are correctly sited in google earth. BUT if I make any analysis in ArcMap 10.4 (eg I selected some of the poylgons and extracted them as a new shapefile) then when I follow the same procedure in QGIS the polygons of the new kml are misaligned as did in the ArcMap!

Comment: And here is the kml with the correctly aligned polygons: https://we.tl/BhjiUcyp7f

Comment: what is your default workspace in arcmap check it once

Comment: What do you mean with default workspace? (I am not a pro user of ArcMap) In the environments, I have current workspace: C:\Users\Andreas\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb    and scratch workspace: C:\Users\Andreas\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb  However I save the exported shapefiles in different folders (not inside gdbs)

Comment: Try to set output coordinate system in environment settings in arcgis and try to export kml.